# apply draggable=false to all images in an HTML page

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a way to add the html attribute "draggable="false" (or some code which does the equivalent)  to all images without writing it inside the tags of every image?

I have about 50 images which need it so wondering if there is a quicker way.

Answers preferebly using CSS or jQuery - thanks in advance

Comment: `$('img').attr('draggable', 'false')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `attr`, `prop` as follow:

```
$('img').attr('draggable', 'false');
```

OR

```
$('img').prop('draggable', false);
```

OR

If you have `draggable` existing to the `img` you can use `removeAttr` to remove it.

```
$('img').removeAttr('draggable');
```